# HTML5 mp4 embbed subtitles

Tags: ffmpeg, html5-video

It is possible to use buildin `mov_text` MP4 subtitles for HTML5 video player?

```
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.66.102
  Duration: 01:28:55.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 908 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 704x400 [SAR 1:1 DAR 44:25], 772 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 129 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #0:2(rus): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
    Stream #0:3(eng): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874), 0 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Extract subtitles as WebVTT:

   ```
   ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -map 0:s:0 subs_rus.vtt -map 0:s:1 subs_eng.vtt
   ```
2. Add the subtitles to your HTML5 `<video>` element:

   ```
   <track src="subs_rus.vtt" kind="subtitles" srclang="ru" label="русский">
   <track src="subs_eng.vtt" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" label="English">
   ```

Comment: It`s impossible to play subtitles without extraction? I would like to work with one file.

Comment: @Hett Not that I know of.